# How can I change colour of reflection/shadows to blue, to match the water?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, image-manipulation, shadows

[image: An evening landscape shot]

Original Pic:

[image]

I have taken and edited the above shot in Lightroom to give an evening effect. I would like to remove the green reflection of trees  on the lake to darker blue or the color of water on the right side of the lake. But I get only black color(Shadows/Reflection) and cannot change the color in that region. I am a beginner and this is my 5th shot, and I am stuck in editing. I tried even reducing exposure/shadows but its still the same. Please let me know how I can proceed.

Comment: In Photoshop, or only using Lightroom?

Comment: Thank You Sir.In Lightroom  if possible or in combination of both.

Comment: Would love to see your adjusted image and get info on technique you used. Would help others looking to accomplish the same. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, where is this shot taken?!

Answer (score 1):

Masking the water portion and doing a hue shift on anything green is probably the easiest way.  This way you don't alter the actual trees but can selectively change colors within the water portion while maintaining the relative color differences.

Comment: Thank You Sir.Please tell me how to go about it if you can share any link/video to the solution suggested it would help me a great deal.Thanks for the time Sir.Looking forward for more inputs from you Sir.

Comment: Go to the layers and click the channels, find the one with the most contrast, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C to grab it. Go back to the layers and add a new layer, then Ctrl+V to paste it. Use levels to get a good contrast, then use threshold to get the area isolated. Duplicate the image, and apply this new layer as a mask. Then use the hue-shift (it is in the image menu? I am not at my computer so I can't check) tool to correct the color how you see fit. If you need more detail, Google some of the terms I have talked about, these are all very common steps to complete.

Comment: It might be easier to match the green reflection to the water color first, THEN apply your effect.

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir.I will try the above steps.It was a great explanation.If you can share a link if you come across something similar or tutorial it would be great to follow watching the steps.Thanks again for everything.Please share the link if you come across it.

Comment: Hello Mike Sir How exactly do I do that quickly.If you look at the above image the color green reflection is not going well with the purple/Blue .So How DO I do That by the solution you suggested . Please explain briefly.Really Interested to do it.